# Does Bitbucket support SSH certificates?

Tags: bitbucket

Trying to figure out if Bitbucket supports SSH certificates for cloning where one could upload the CA cert instead of just regular SSH public key, was not able to find reference to it anywhere in docs.

Edit: This is the doc where I mainly looked: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/